# create a wizard

Tags: c#, winforms, wizard

I want to implement a wizard using winforms and VS 2010.

I've got this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120607/Simple-Wizard-for-WinForms), but as I'm new to Visual Studio and C# I don't really understand it.

Could someone help me out?

My main problem is that I don't know where to put the listings in this tutorial?

Should I put all the code in one class? Or in one form.cs? How is it divided?

greetz

Bl!tz

Comment: If you are completely new to VS and C# I would look at going for more of a "Hello World" tutorial. The one you have listed deals with things like interfaces, which is more advanced than the level you have described. Try http://www.functionx.com/csharp/Lesson01.htm

Comment: Is it for setup/install purpose ?

Comment: @Patrick i made some things with java in the past years but not with a GUI.

Comment: @HichemC NO it's for a calcualtion whre the user goes through some steps and has to enter some numbers and pick some date and time

Comment: Does it can be done with WPF instead ?

Comment: is it easier with WPF? i'm just starting to learn C#. is it a big differnce between winforms and WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you will need to create a UserControl (right-click your project, New... User Control) for each page of the Wizard, and you will need to implement IWizardPage on your UserControl. Than you have your WizardHost which is a single Form.

So to answer your question you will have one Form and a UserControl for each page of the Wizard.

Comment: the form contains the back and next buttons(which were on every page of the wizard the same) and the user controls contains my datetimepicker, textboxes and labels which were on every wizardpage different? is this right?

Comment: thank you this helps me a little bit further

Comment: @user1414157 please mark as answer if this has helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example, use groupboxes, and set them all on visibility hidden, but only show the first one, then when u click the button  u set the visibility of the first groupbox to hidden, and the set the visibility of the 2e one to show.

a groupbox can contain controls, so that u wont have to show or hide individual controls